# App crashes from signed APK but not Android studio

Tags: android

My application runs just fine when installed from Android studio but as soon as I install and signed APK to any device the app will not run. Below is a crash dump from a friends device that was provided from the Google Play Developer Console. Obviously it has something to do with the layout but I'm not sure what is causing it in the release build but not while testing. No Errors show up when I'm testing it on my device and there are no errors in android studio. I'm fairly new to developing so I am not sure what to do. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.j.a.p/com.j.a.p.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at android.support.v7.a.w.a(SourceFile:257)
        at android.support.v7.a.p.setContentView(SourceFile:109)
        at com.j.a.p.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.support.design.internal.c.a(SourceFile:97)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(SourceFile:165)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(SourceFile:94)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error creating LayoutManager android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.a(SourceFile:540)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(SourceFile:485)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView.<init>(SourceFile:39)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView.<init>(SourceFile:35)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:492)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.a(SourceFile:537)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet, int, int]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:492)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.a(SourceFile:532)
        ... 36 more
```

Comment: You probably have proguard enabled, which is messing with the NavigationMenu view

Comment: for a try just disable proguard and try building signed apk if that works than you should update your proguard file else problem is different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try deleting proguard directory in your project On any proguard files such as 
proguard-android.txt or proguard-rules.pro.

2nd option -  try in your build.gradle file

```
 buildTypes {

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

        }
    }
```

Use any of the options or a combination of both

Comment: The second option with debug set to true and release set to false worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you added a library like glide which needs to be mentioned in proguard, you should add the needed line to your proguard-rules.pro